# R using dcast,melt and concatenation to reshape data frame

Tags: r, reshape, reshape2, dcast

I have a data frame as follows:

```
mydf <- data.frame(Term = c('dog','cat','lion','tiger','pigeon','vulture'), Category = c('pet','pet','wild','wild','pet','wild'),
    Count = c(12,14,19,7,11,10), Rate = c(0.4,0.7,0.3,0.6,0.1,0.8), Brand = c('GS','GS','MN','MN','PG','MN')    )
```

Resulting in data frame:

```
     Term Category Count Rate Brand
1     dog      pet    12  0.4    GS
2     cat      pet    14  0.7    GS
3    lion     wild    19  0.3    MN
4   tiger     wild     7  0.6    MN
5  pigeon      pet    11  0.1    PG
6 vulture     wild    10  0.8    MN
```

I wish to transform this data frame into following `resultDF`

```
Category         pet              wild              
Term             dog,cat,pigeon   lion,tiger,vulture
Countlessthan13  dog,pigeon       tiger,vulture     
Ratemorethan0.5  cat              tiger,vulture     
Brand            GS,PG            MN
```

The row headings indicate the operations like Countlessthan13 means that Count < 13 is applied to the terms and then grouped.
Also note that brand name is unique and not reapeated.

I have tried dcast and melt...but not getting desired results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can do this using `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(mydf)`), grouped by 'Category', create some summarise columns by `paste`ing the `unique` values of 'Term' where 'Count' is less than 13 or 'Rate' greater than 0.5, along with `paste`ing the `unique` elements of 'Brand'.

```
library(data.table)
dt <- setDT(mydf)[, .(Term = paste(unique(Term), collapse=","),
                      Countlesstthan13 =  paste(unique(Term[Count < 13]), collapse=","),

                      Ratemorethan0.5 = paste(unique(Term[Rate > 0.5]), collapse=","), 
                      Brand = paste(unique(Brand), collapse=",")), by = Category]
```

From the summarised dataset ('dt'), we `melt` to 'long' format by specifying the 'id.var' as 'Category', then `dcast` it back to 'wide' format.

```
dcast(melt(dt, id.var = "Category", variable.name = "category"),
                            category ~Category, value.var = "value")
#           category            pet               wild
#1:             Term dog,cat,pigeon lion,tiger,vulture
#2: Countlesstthan13     dog,pigeon      tiger,vulture
#3:  Ratemorethan0.5            cat      tiger,vulture
#4:            Brand          GS,PG                 MN
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks Akrun..made my day !